# counting excel values by dynamic date

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have sheet like this:
[image]

The date spans across few months (but have constant number of entries, lets say there are 100 dates). That I'd like to do is to sum values for month and year, that are entered in  B1 and B2 cells. I wanted to use SUMIFS, and use cell reference like this:

```
SUMIFS(B5:B1005;A5:A1005;">DATE(B1;B2;1)";A5:A1005;"<DATE(B1;B2+1;1)")
```

But I got 0 as result. And don't look that year is 2016 while dates are 2015- it doesn't work with 2015 either. All examples I found use static criterion, not cell reference. Is it possible to archive such result using only functions?

Comment: I think you've wrapped the wrong part of the equation as text (and not used an inequality) - try this `SUMIFS(B5:B1005;A5:A1005;">="&DATE(B1;B2;1);A5:A1005;"<"&DATE(B1;B2+1;1))`.

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem!

Answer (score 0):

if you would like a helper column, you could do it like this:

In C5 put

```
=IF(AND(MONTH(A5)=$B$2,YEAR(A5)=$B$1),1,0)
```

and drag down.

In the Sum field you would then simply put

```
=SUMIF(C5:C1005,1,B5:B1005)
```

If you are using a Non-English Excel, then replace the `:` with `;`.

Comment: Problem is that I'll have to use it this function multiple times for different months, so I can't add for example 6 new columns to calculate it.